# Chart.JS reduce bundle size using specific charts

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

In the documentation of Chart.JS at the [Quick start](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#quick-start) it says when importing the package as `import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'` it will include all the features.

I only wanted to use the **line chart** but there is no documentation on how to use it. In the part of [Bundle optimization](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#bundle-optimization) it says *"you need to import and register the components that are needed in your application"* which I do not get how can I only import the components that are needed for the line chart.

I have to do this since the disk space is very limited for the environment that I am developing.

Answer (score 1):

You can import this away:

```js
  import {
    Chart,
    LineController,
    LineElement,
    LinearScale,
    CategoryScale,
    PointElement,
  } from "chart.js";
  Chart.register(
    LineController,
    LineElement,
    LinearScale,
    CategoryScale,
    PointElement
  );
```

I had already answered this issue on github

> https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/11247

Answer (score 0):

I had done it using [`react-chartjs-2`](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/) with great documentation. If anyone also wants to use it, here are the [examples](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/examples/).

Thanks to this article [4 Ways to Shrink Your Javascript Bundle by 50%](https://lawnchamp.medium.com/4-ways-to-shrink-your-javascript-bundle-by-50-8ba9fcb4c3b4), using the step #4.